# SoapUi: Transferring a response value to a temporary property (missing a non persisting target scope)

Tags: groovy, soapui

Using SoapUI Pro 5.0

I know how to transfer response values to any scoped property (test suite, test case, etc.).

My problem is, that such scoped properties:

1. must already exist in the target scope
2. are persisted at the end in the project configuration file. So after each run this configuration file is changed, what is a nightmare for source control.

I need this value only one or two step(s) later for doing complex verifications (usingg a Script-TestStep).

The "Property Transfer"-TestStep is very powerful for extracting from known sources and transferring to known targets. As target one even can choose a Script-TestStep from the same TestCase. But I did not find any hint how to bind the value to be transferred to - let's say - a declared variable within the target script.

Using the context (e.g. context.getProperties().put( 'MY_PROP_NAME', transferValue ) would be nice but the context is not available within the "Property Transfer"-TestStep. The only possibility I figured out is following script code in a Script-TestStep:

```
def xmlResponse = XMLNamespaceRemover.removeNamespaces(context.expand( '${mySoapTestStep#Response}' ));
def node = new groovy.util.XmlParser(false,false).parseText(xmlResponse);
def transferValue = node["Body"]["tag1"]["tag2"].text();
context.getProperties().put( 'MY_PROP_NAME', transferValue )
```

Any ideas how to solve this using the "Property Transfer" TestStep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you can just use:

```
def MY_PROP_NAME = context.expand( '${mySoapTestStep#Response//*:Body/*:tag1/*:tag2}' )
```

Alternatively, you can use a Property Transfer step to transfer your value to a TestCase Property - which, as you pointed out, must already exist. In order to get around the problem you mentioned of persisting and thereby messing around with source control, you can create a TearDown script:

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("MY_PROP_NAME", "default")
```

Comment: The first proposal does not seem to work (no value in MY_PROP_NAME). I do not see how the namespace of tag1 and tag2 can be specified.

Comment: The trick with the teardown script seems to be a valuable approach.

Comment: Added the namespaces.